# File system enumerator throwing error

Tags: c#, .net, ioexception

I am calling the following code on a mapped folder to another share

```
private static void CheckFileNaming(string path)
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach (var fi in di.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        if (fi.Name.EndsWith(".battxt"))
        {
            var name = fi.FullName.Substring(0, fi.FullName.Length - 3);
            TaskLogger("Rename " + fi.FullName + " to " + name);
            File.Move(fi.FullName, name);
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting the error

```
2016-04-26 11:00:58Z: Error occurred:    
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()
   at Centrica.EMT.SE.CloudMaster.Program.CheckFileNaming(String path)
   at Centrica.EMT.SE.CloudMaster.Program.RunCombiner(String modelVersion, String pythonVersion)
2016-04-26 11:00:58Z: Invalid Signature.
```

Which seems to imply there is a problem with simply enumerating the files but I have never seen this error before and cannot find anything on google. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: @kyle Clearly it's happening when they call `EnumerateFiles()` on the `foreach (var fi in di.EnumerateFiles())` line.  Specifically it's failing to create the enumerable.

Comment: Is this on a UNC path? This might be relevant: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2686098

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a Win32 error, "Invalid Signature". This suggests that a security negotiation failed, which in turn suggests that you're trying to enumerate files on a remote file system. This may mean that your security credentials are invalid, or that your client doesn't support a SMB version high enough for the server to accept.

The following KB article may be relevant: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2686098

But the gist is: your code is most likely not to blame, this is system/network-admin issue. Make sure the systems are configured and updated properly, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds right. This is on Azure Batch, the code is executing on a batch VM, mapping a local drive on the VM to a location in Azure File Storage. It worked at the start of the program or it wouldn't have gotten that far but perhaps something happened to invalidate the credentials halfway through execution so when it tried to re-access it failed. Also would an enumeration fail potentially if another process was accessing one of the files? I would have thought an enumeration was read only but perhaps not

Comment: @NZJames Well, even enumeration requires some kind of synchronization, but as far as I'm aware, the FS/OS pretends that you're enumerating an immutable snapshot of the drive, so you can read out-of-date information, but you shouldn't be impacted by someone else writing/deleting something. As for why the operation only fails at some point - the KB article I linked to shows that the errors may differ based on the kind of operation you're performing. A file enumeration would fall into the `dir` group - maybe you're doing some other kind of operation that works fine in your other case?

Comment: Curious: How did you figure from the OP's question that it's specifically "Invalid Signature" error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your code. This could be because of permission issues over the files in the directory.

```
System.Security.SecurityException:
The caller does not have the required permission.
```

This could be a possible issue with the directory on which you are iterating. Make sure your application have full access(off course at least read) on the directory.